# Show Price based on the customer country code in woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, ip-address

I have 3  fields India , Saudi and Uae . In that field admin can add price of products based on country If a customer from India is viewing the site i want to show value entered in India. I'm getting country code but comparison not working

```
function _wp_get_ip() {
$ip = '127.0.0.1';

if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {
    //check ip from share internet
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    //to check ip is pass from proxy
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} elseif( ! empty( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip_array = explode( ',', $ip );
$ip_array = array_map( 'trim', $ip_array );

if ( $ip_array[0] == '::1' ) {
    $ip_array[0] = '127.0.0.1';
}

return $ip_array[0];
}

 function _wp_get_country_code() {
 $url = 'https://ipinfo.io/' . _wp_get_ip() . '/country/?token=814bcab7ccbe41';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
// This is what solved the issue (Accepting gzip encoding)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");     
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','product_custom_price');
function product_custom_price(){
global $post;
$_postID = $post->ID;
$product = get_product( $_postID );
$india = get_field('india' , $post->ID); //loads custom meta data 
$uae = get_field('uae' , $post->ID); //loads custom meta data 
$saudi = get_field('saudi_arabia' , $post->ID); //loads custom meta data 
$return_price = $product->get_regular_price(); //default to regular price
$country_code = _wp_get_country_code();
$a = "IN";

if($country_code == $a ){

$return_price = $india;

}

return $return_price;
}
```

Comment: What if someone is using a VPN?

Comment: It's unclear what part of the code isn't working. Please call out the specific line that isn't getting the expected result.

Comment: if($country_code == $a ){

$return_price = $india;

}

Comment: this is not working